# User Control to Excute Page Class Method (Dynamicly)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have many aspx pages which inherits a base Class.
base class has a method name "GetGroupID", This method returns different data depends which page i am on, now few pages need to override this method (which is fine).

Problem:
I have user control which is placed in almost all pages, now this user control Accessess GetGroupID method from page base class, which is fine as long as i know page class name, since I have so many pages, one base class and one user control...**it would be niceif I can get Page Class name from UserControl and execute the base method dynamically.**

Curreny I have following code which works within UserControl

```
Dim c As homepage = CType(Me.Page, homepage)
Call c.getGroupID
```

However in above example I know the Page Class name (homepage), but lets say i am on a different page which has a classname "portal", it would be impossible for me to keep track of so many pages.

I would like to excute the method in base class within user control, and I would like to override this method for certain pages.

please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let the base-page implement a custom `interface`, for example `IGroupable` with a method `GetgroupId`. Then you only have to know in the `UserControl` that it's `Page` ***is*** `IGroupable`(either directly or through inheritance) and you know for  sure that it has a method `GetgroupId`.

```
Public Interface IGroupable
    Function GetGroupId() As Int32
End Interface

Class BasePage
    Inherits Page
    Implements IGroupable
    Public Overridable Function GetGroupId() As Integer Implements IGroupable.GetGroupId
        Return 1
    End Function
End Class

Class ChildPage
    Inherits BasePage
    ' default implementation of GetGroupId from base page '
End Class

Class SpecialPage
    Inherits BasePage
    ' override it here since it has a different implementation than in the base page '
    Public Overrides Function GetGroupId() As Integer
        Return 2
    End Function
End Class
```

You get the id in the `UserControl` in this way:

```
Class UserControl1
    Inherits UserControl
    Dim id As Int32 = DirectCast(Me.Page, IGroupable).GetGroupId()
End Class
```

Comment: with this approache i need to force all my pages to implement an interface (fine I guess)...also currently my method is within Page BASE class. I would like under user control to exeute method "GetGroupId" from Page's base class and ONLY on few pages I need to override GetGroupId pages. With your interface approach i guess my base class method will be ignored?

Comment: @highwingers: Edited my answer slightly. You could let the base page implement that interface and override the method in each child page where it differs from the default implementation.

Comment: very interesting, never though I could do nice hacks with Interfaces:)

Comment: Actually that's not a hack but simply OOP. That's why interfaces (or inheritance in general) exist.